# How can i record the expect session without showing the output on the stdout?

Tags: expect

I want the output of expect script to go into a log file.It seems pretty easy to do with `log_file` command but the problem is that i just want the output to go to the log file.
when i do

```
 log_user 0
 log_file nameoflogfile
```

the log file gets created with it contents but output is also diplayed on the screen.how do i suppress the output comming to stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you need to write `log_file -a the-log-file` here. According to the Expect manual:

> The `−a` flag forces output to be logged that was suppressed by the
>   `log_user` command.

By the way, outputs generated by the `puts` commands would not be sent to the log file created by `log_file`. You may consider using `send_*` commands (like `send_user`) instead of `puts`.